# post__not_in not getting excluded

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to exclude some posts with a custom meta_key within the hook `pre_get_posts` but for some reason is not working, the posts are not getting excluded. Taxonomies to be excluded work, but posts no.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts' , 'changeCourseCountry');
function changeCourseCountry($query){
    global $wpdb;
    $tax_query_merge = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'course_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('short-courses', 'mega-course'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
    );
    $tax_query = array_merge($tax_query, $tax_query_merge);
    $exclude = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_video_course'"); // here I get an array of posts
    $query->set('tax_query' ,$tax_query);
    $query->set('post__not_in', $exlcude);
    return $query
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is already solved but you got the typo error: $query->set('post__not_in', $exlcude); should it be $exclude?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following instead of getting the column data,

```
$exclude = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_video_course'"); // here I get an array of posts
```

So it will be ,

```
add_action('pre_get_posts' , 'changeCourseCountry');
function changeCourseCountry($query){
    global $wpdb;
    $tax_query_merge = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'course_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('short-courses', 'mega-course'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
    );
    $tax_query = array_merge($tax_query, $tax_query_merge);
    $exclude = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_video_course'",ARRAY_A); // here I get an array of posts
    $query->set('tax_query' ,$tax_query);
    $query->set('post__not_in', $exlcude);
    return $query;
}
```

Also if you need multiple IDs then you need to use `get_results` and loop the array in foreach.

I also added ARRAY_A to $wpdb query to retrive the array.

Comment: Same thing, not excluding them, if I do `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;` For Some reason they are not being added. `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ncvpf_posts.ID FROM ncvpf_posts LEFT JOIN ncvpf_term_relationships ON (ncvpf_posts.ID = ncvpf_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ncvpf_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (24) ) AND ncvpf_posts.post_type = 'course' AND (ncvpf_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR ncvpf_posts.post_status = 'zerobalance') GROUP BY ncvpf_posts.ID ORDER BY ncvpf_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12`

Comment: Also I don't need get_row, I need get_col, because I want to exclude any posts that are in that array. Get row retrieves only the first row. So the problem is in: `$query->set('post__not_in', $exlcude);` as everything else is ok.

Comment: try to print and check if you are getting the array or not. print_r($exlcude)

Comment: I am getting what I need with get_col, tried with your suggestion, but it gets only an array with one element. So the array is not the issue.

Comment: Checked function `parse_tax_quer`y located in `class-wp-query.php` and indeed there is nothing related to `post__not_in` but new wp query uses it.

Comment: Found the issue, array had duplicate values and needed to do an array_unique.